# PubSub: is it possible to get last message for a late subscriber?

Tags: activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I'm going to use a publish subscribe mechanism (AWS SNS / activeMQ).

I wonder if there is a possibility to put a message on a topic with expiration time (5 minutes in my case), so that a consumer which subscribed to that topic will get it even if it subscribed after the message was pushed.

For example, Every 5 minutes I push a message "the sensor measured 5 units" to the topic "sensor#3". I would like a new subscriber to the topic to get the last message, and not have to wait 5 minutes to get a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topics do not retain messages when there are no consumers.  You need to create a Durable Topic Subscription in order to store messages that were sent while your consumer is offline.

ActiveMQ does have a feature called [retroactive consumers](http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html) which will attempt to deliver older messages to a Topic subscription if they still happen to be in the memory cache but there is no guarantee that this will happen so don't count on it to be 100% reliable.

Comment: Under http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html it says: "The subscription recovery policy allows you to go back in time when you subscribe to a topic" and describes different policies like "Keep a fixed count of last messages" policy. That seems to describe a guarantee that these massages are kept in the topic even if there are no subscribers?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SNS, you can subscribe an SQS queue to it. Then instead of subscribing to the topic directly, you can poll the queue and receive any messages sitting there. There are some design concerns you should consider though, such as SQS messages may be delivered out of order or multiple times.